# Олимпиадная задача, непонятная работа компилятора. Выборы в США

Tags: c++, map, компилятор, олимпиада, set

Решил задачу, прошёл данные в условии тесты, но когда отправляю задачу на проверку не проходятся даже данные в условии тесты. Если же просто скопипастить и вывести правильный ответ из первого теста в условии, то первый тест пройдёт.

**ВЫБОРЫ В США** (Название задачи)

**Ссылка на информатикс:** https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=25861&chapterid=3770#1

**Условие:** Как известно, в США президент выбирается не прямым голосованием, а путём двухуровневого голосования. Сначала проводятся выборы в каждом штате, и определяется победитель выборов в данном штате. Затем проводятся государственные выборы: на этих выборах каждый штат имеет определённое число голосов — число выборщиков от этого штата. На практике все выборщики от штата голосуют в соответствии с результатами голосования внутри штата, то есть на заключительной стадии выборов в голосовании участвуют штаты, имеющие различное число голосов.

На этот раз вам известно число выборщиков от каждого штата США и результаты голосования каждого гражданина США (а также в каком штате проживает данный гражданин).

Вам необходимо подвести результаты голосования: сначала определить результаты голосования в каждом штате и определить, за кого из кандидатов отданы голоса выборщиков данного штата. Далее необходимо подвести результаты голосования выборщиков по всем штатам.

**Входные данные:** Первая строка входных данных содержит количество штатов в США N (1≤N≤100000). Далее идёт N строк, описывающих штаты США, каждая строка состоит из названия штата и числа выборщиков от этого штата. На следующей строке задано число M (1≤M≤100000)— количество проголосовавших на выборах. В следующих M строках идут записи результатов голосования по каждому из участников голосования. Одна строка соответствует одному избирателю. Записи имеют следующий вид: название штата, имя кандидата, за которого проголосовал данный избиратель. Названия штатов и имена кандидатов не содержат пробелов.

**Выходные данные:** Выведите список кандидатов, упорядоченный по убыванию числа голосов выборщиков, полученных за данного кандидата, а при равенстве числа голосов выборщиков — в лексикографическом порядке. После имени кандидата выведите число набранных им голосов.

Если в каком-либо штате два или более кандидатов набрали одинаковое число голосов, то все голоса выборщиков этого штата получает наименьший в лексикографическом порядке кандидат из числа победителей в этом штате.

Гарантируется, что в каждом штате проголосовал хотя бы один избиратель.

**Тесты:**

**ВВОД1:** 
2 
Florida 25 
Pennsylvania 23 
11 
Florida Gore 
Pennsylvania Gore 
Florida Bush 
Pennsylvania Gore 
Pennsylvania Bush 
Florida Gore 
Pennsylvania Gore 
Florida Bush 
Pennsylvania Gore 
Florida Bush 
Pennsylvania Gore

**ВЫВОД1:** 
Bush 25 
Gore 23

**ВВОД2:** 
3 
Florida 5 
Pennsylvania 4 
Alaska 3 
4 
Florida Gore 
Pennsylvania Obama 
Pennsylvania Clinton 
Alaska Bush

**ВЫВОД2:** 
Gore 5 
Clinton 4 
Bush 3 
Obama 0

**Примечание к тестам:**
В Florida 2 избирателя голосует за Gore и три избирателя за Bush, поэтому 25 голосов выборщиков от Florida получает Bush. В Pennsylvania побеждает Gore (5 голосов против 1), поэтому Gore получает 23 голоса выборщиков от Pennsylvania.

В Florida побеждает Gore (5 голосов выборщиков), в Alaska — Bush (2 голоса выборщиков). В Pennsylvania два кандидата набрали наибольшее число голосов (по 1), поэтому 4 голоса выборщиков от этого штата получает Clinton, т.к. он идет раньше в лексикографическом порядке.

**МОЁ РЕШЕНИЕ (Можете протестировать на приведённых выше тестах и убедиться, что выводится правильный ответ)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    map <pair<string,string>, int> e; // e[make_pair("Florida", "Gore")] = 2;

    map <string, int> states; // states["Florida"] = 25;

    int n,m,p; // n - 2; m - 11; p - 25, 23;

    string state,guy;

    vector <pair<int,string>> s; // s[0] = 25, "Bush"; Массив для ответа

    pair <string,string> w; // {"Florida", "Gore"}; w - от слова winner;

    set <string> people; // Gore, Bush; Здесь будут люди получившие 0 голосов, постепенно этот сет будет уменьшаться по мере получения голосов кандидатами

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        cin >> state >> p;
        states[state] = p;
    }
    cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        cin >> state >> guy;
        ++e[make_pair(state, guy)];
        people.insert(guy);
    }

    for (auto it = e.begin(); it != e.end(); ++it){
        w = it->first; // по умолчанию
        auto it2 = it; // для проверки следующего элемента и сравнения его с предыдущим
        ++it2;
        while ((it2 != e.end()) && ((it->first).first == (it2->first).first)){ // пока в словаре встречаются голоса, отданные В ОДНОМ И ТОМ ЖЕ штате то есть я собираю все голоса из одного штата и сравниваю их попарно поддерживая макс
            if (it->second < it2->second){ // При равенстве ничего делать не нужно тк словарь уже отсортирован лексикографически
                w = it2->first; // новый победитель в данном штате
            }
            ++it; // Новая пара
            ++it2; // Новая пара
        }
        s.push_back(make_pair(states[w.first], w.second)); // 25, "Bush"
    }

    sort(begin(s), end(s)); reverse(begin(s), end(s)); // Сортируем по убыванию

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) s.size(); ++i){
        people.erase(s[i].second); // Если данный человек есть в массиве s то у него положительное колво голосов
        if (i != (int) s.size() - 1){
            cout << s[i].second << " " << s[i].first << endl;
        } else {cout << s[i].second << " " << s[i].first;}
    }

    if (people.size() > 0){ // Теперь здесь остались кандидаты которые не получили ни одного голоса
        cout << endl;
        for (auto i : people){
            cout << i << " " << 0 << endl;
        }
    }
    //cout << "Bush" << " " << 25 << endl; // Если вывести это, то первый тест проходит
    //cout << "Gore" << " " << 23;
    return 0;
}
```

Комментарии основаны на 1 тесте.

Comment: Если в каком-либо штате два или более кандидатов набрали одинаковое число голосов, то все голоса выборщиков этого штата получает наименьший в лексикографическом порядке кандидат из числа победителей в этом штате - угараю с этого условия. Вот поэтому программистам не сильно доверяют создание автоматизированной избирательной системы

Comment: Не совсем понял вашу проблему - вы говорите, что результат проги верный... Так чем тогда мы можем вам помочь если он и так правильный?

Comment: и совет по поводу именования переменных: вместо того, чтобы именовать переменную `w` и в комменте подписывать ее как `winner` - почему не назвать саму переменную `winner`? А точнее `winners`

Comment: и у вас почему то аж три переменные для учета итоговых результатов... Зачем? Для этого достаточно одной мапки!

Comment: Программа выводит правильный ответ но этот же тест не проходит через систему

Comment: в таком случае обращайтесь к создателям тэста - мы то чем вам можем помочь?

Comment: Это парадокс. Если вывести cout << "Bush" << " " << 25 << endl; cout << "Gore" << " " << 23; то тогда тест пройдёт. А если ЭТОТ ЖЕ ответ выводит моя программа то тест засчитывается как неправильный

Comment: в таком случае есть только 2 варинта: либо ваша прога выводит все таки не то, что вы думаете, либо проблема с тестом

Comment: В таком случае можете пожалуйста прогнать мою программу по первому тесту из условия и сравнить с ответом. Может мне пора очки купить....

Comment: нет не могу - у меня на это нет времени и желания. Вы должны сами уметь отличать верный результат от неверного, потому что никто кроме вас не может сказать какой, собственно, это результат: тот что вы и ожидали получить или нет

Comment: у меня ошибка была в том, что записи результатов голосования на информатикс нужно считывать пока входной файл не пуст, а я решаю на другой платформе, там нужно вводить число m

Comment: я не буду прикреплять правильное решение т.к. эта задачка с Сириуса с отбора на программу и она достаточно непростая. Если я выложу решение, то это будет нечестно по отношению к другим участникам отбора :)