# Задача c++ Выборы в США-2

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Первая строка входных данных содержит количество штатов в США N (1≤N≤100000). Далее идёт N строк, описывающих штаты США, каждая строка состоит из названия штата и числа выборщиков от этого штата. На следующей строке задано число M (1≤M≤100000)— количество проголосовавших на выборах. В следующих M строках идут записи результатов голосования по каждому из участников голосования. Одна строка соответствует одному избирателю. Записи имеют следующий вид: название штата, имя кандидата, за которого проголосовал данный избиратель. Названия штатов и имена кандидатов не содержат пробелов.

Выходные данные

Выведите список кандидатов, упорядоченный по убыванию числа голосов выборщиков, полученных за данного кандидата, а при равенстве числа голосов выборщиков — в лексикографическом порядке. После имени кандидата выведите число набранных им голосов.

Если в каком-либо штате два или более кандидатов набрали одинаковое число голосов, то все голоса выборщиков этого штата получает наименьший в лексикографическом порядке кандидат из числа победителей в этом штате.

Гарантируется, что в каждом штате проголосовал хотя бы один избиратель.

Примечание к примерам тестов

В Florida 2 избирателя голосует за Gore и три избирателя за Bush, поэтому 25 голосов выборщиков от Florida получает Bush. В Pennsylvania побеждает Gore (5 голосов против 1), поэтому Gore получает 23 голоса выборщиков от Pennsylvania.

В Florida побеждает Gore (5 голосов выборщиков), в Alaska — Bush (2 голоса выборщиков). В Pennsylvania два кандидата набрали наибольшее число голосов (по 1), поэтому 4 голоса выборщиков от этого штата получает Clinton, т.к. он идет раньше в лексикографическом порядке.
**Ввод**
2
Florida 25
Pennsylvania 23
11
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Gore
Pennsylvania Bush
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Gore
**Вывод**
Bush 25
Gore 23
**Ввод**
3
Florida 4
Pennsylvania 4
Alaska 4
4
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Obama
Pennsylvania Clinton
Alaska Bush
**Вывод**
Gore 5
Clinton 4
Bush 3
Obama 0

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int statesCount;
cin >> statesCount;

map<string, int> states;
string state;
int stateElectorsCount;
for (int i = 0; i < statesCount; i++)
{
cin >> state >> stateElectorsCount;
states[state] = stateElectorsCount;
}

int electorsTotalCount;
cin >> electorsTotalCount;

map < string, map < string, int>> votes;
string candidate;
set<string> candidates;
for (int i = 0; i < electorsTotalCount; i++)
{
cin >> state >> candidate;
votes[state][candidate] += 1;
candidates.insert(candidate);
}

int maxVotes = 0;
string winner;
map<string, int> winners;
for (auto const& vote : votes)
{
maxVotes = 0;
for (auto const& candidateVotes : vote.second)
{
if (maxVotes < candidateVotes.second)
{
maxVotes = candidateVotes.second;
winner = candidateVotes.first;
}
}

winners[winner] += states[vote.first];
candidates.erase(winner);
}

vector<pair<int, string>> res;
for (auto const&result : winners)
{
res.push_back(make_pair(result.second, result.first));
}

struct cmp
{
inline bool operator() (const pair<int, string>& a, const pair<int, string>& b)
{
return a.first != b.first ? a.first > b.first : a.second < b.second;
}
};

sort(res.begin(), res.end(), cmp());

for (auto const& result : res)
{
cout << result.second << " " << result.first << endl;
}

for (auto const& looser : candidates)
{
cout << looser << " 0" << endl;
}
}
```

Пишет неверный ответ, 2 часа тестов ничего не дали. Не могли бы люди, разбирающиеся в плюсах помочь?

Comment: Я не вижу вопроса. Вижу только какой-то непонятный код и задачу. Задайте вопрос!

Comment: Кнопку править, думаю, вы нашли) Гайд, как задавать вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и как форматировать https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5860/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1188778/195342, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1192684/195342

Comment: @Harry, в первом случае проблема была в сайте проверки и том, что там была задача для пайтона, вторая - пайтон, который ещё и видимый тест даже не проходит). Я прошу помощи на плюсах

Comment: Вам нужен код, или подсказка?

Comment: А я и не закрывал вопрос, как дубликат...

Comment: @Neuro любую помощь)

Comment: @Sheep ну код написанный на скорую руку я скинул

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что этот код работает хорошо, но на тестовых он прошел.
Из описания просканили данные в мапы, покрутили их, отсортили по числу голосов, и вывели

```
#define fca(a,s) for(const auto & a: s)
#define incr(i,a,b) for (ll i=a; i<b; ++i)
inline void solve(){
    ll n, mans;
    string stt, pres;
    cin >> n;
    map <string, int> states;
    map <string, map<string,int>> foundingfathers;
    map <string, int> pre_ans;
    map <int ,string, greater<int>> ans;
    incr(i,0,n){
        cin >> stt >> mans;
        states[stt]=mans;
    } 
    while (cin >> stt >> pres){
        pre_ans[pres] = 0;
        foundingfathers[stt][pres]++;
    }
    fca(a,foundingfathers){
        auto it = max_element(a.second.begin(), a.second.end(),[](const std::pair<string,int>& a, const std::pair<string,int>& b)->bool{ return a.second < b.second; } );;
        pre_ans[it->first] = states[a.first];
    }
    fca(a, pre_ans){
        ans[a.second] = a.first;
    }
    fca(a, ans){
        cout << a.second << " " << a.first <<nl;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `#define fca`,`#define incr` - вредные советы. :/

Comment: Шаблон от олимпиадного программирования, такие шаблоны там это наоборот полезные советы

Comment: Для чистого олимпиадника *возможно*. А если он решает задачи чтобы потом работать, и попробует использовать это на работе - вредно.

Comment: бывают только олимпиадники, и не олимпиадники; на информатиксе обычно решают точно не олимпиадники

Comment: Также пишет, что неверный ответ, какой тест не проходит посмотреть я не могу, сам придумать, на котором логика ломается так и не смог

Comment: попробуйте провести такой тест 
3
a 1
b 1
c 1
5
a a
a b 
b b
b a
c e